# C++ Namespace - Function Declaration in Header File and Definition in Source File

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm new to C++ and I encountered the following problem. I have a project whose file structure is like this:

```
[untitled]
  -> main.cpp
  -> functions.h
  -> definition.cpp
```

The `functions.h` file looks like this:

```cpp
#ifndef UNTITLED_FUNCTIONS_H
#define UNTITLED_FUNCTIONS_H

namespace mynamespace {

void myfunction();

}

#endif //UNTITLED_FUNCTIONS_H
```

The `main.cpp` file looks like this:

```cpp
#include "functions.h"

using namespace mynamespace;

int main() {
    myfunction();
    return 0;
}
```

And the `definition.cpp` file looks like this:

```cpp
#include "functions.h"

using namespace mynamespace;

void myfunction() {}
```

Then the compiler gives me the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "mynamespace::myfunction()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm using a mac and using CLion as my IDE.

If I change the file `definition.cpp` as in the following:

```cpp
#include "functions.h"

void mynamespace::myfunction() {}
```

Then it compiles successfully. I am wondering why writing "using namespace mynamespace;" doesn't work.

Comment: `using namespace mynamespace;` has no effect on declarations below. You are declaring `myfunction` in the global namespace.

Comment: To elaborate on @n.m.couldbeanAI, what if definitions.cpp also had the statement `using namespace std;`, which namespace would you expect the implementation of myfunction to be under?

Comment: You should put the function's definition (in the `definition.cpp` file) into the namespace as well: `namespace mynamespace { void myfunction() { } }`

Comment: Ah. So is it true that `using namespace mynamespace;` has effect when a function is called but no effect on declarations?

Comment: `using namespace mynamespace;` means "when looking for the symbol, check over here in `mynamespace` for it".  It does not mean "when I **declare** a symbol, feel free to stick it over there in `mynamespace`."

Comment: You will do yourself a huge, huge favor if you completely forget that "using namespace" exists in C++ until, at least, there's more familiarity with core C++ fundamentals. Many tears have been shed after all sorts of crazy things happened because the consequences of "using namespace", especially "using namespace std" were ...surprising.